# Python List Hierarchy

Tags: python

I am dealing with some complicated python lists containing tuples and dictionaries. how is it possible to get the hierarchy of a python list like this:

> [ mean: -17.71262, std: 1.74160, params: {'epsilon': 0, 'C': 1, 'gamma':
>   0.0001} mean: -13.05773, std: 2.16184, params: {'epsilon': 0, 'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0101} mean: -17.64222, std: 1.47564, params: {'epsilon': 4,
>   'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001} mean: -13.61797, std: 1.95222, params:
>   {'epsilon': 4, 'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0101} ]

it is a list of 4 items each of them is a tuple of 3 items and the third tuple item is a dictionary with three keys

it is a result of scikit learn grid search with cross validation and this is the used code:

> param_grid={'C':np.arange(1,50000,25000),'epsilon':np.arange(0,8,4),'gamma':np.arange(0.0001,0.02,0.02)} 
>   opt=GridSearchCV(SVR(),param_grid,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',n_jobs=8,cv=3, verbose=1) 
>   opt.fit(tvr_sets[:,:2],tvr_sets[:,2])
>   print(opt.grid_scores_)

is there a python command that can describe this hierarchy?

Comment: Your list is a syntax error.

Comment: What do you mean "get the hierarchy"?  What is "the hierarchy"?

Comment: this is how I am getting it from the scikit-learn function

Comment: I mean knowing that "it is a list of 4 items each of them is a tuple of 3 items and the third tuple item is a dictionary with three keys"
maybe the word "structure" is more relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is returned from a grid search and cross-validation. This is not a tuple it is a list as far as I am concerned but it is rather unimportant. You have a list with each output from the grid search.

Each element is the result of that particular `params`

```
 GridSearch & Cross-validation => {std: float, mean: float, params: {Your grid search params}}
```

The `std/mean` arise from the cross-validation process.

Based on the comments

> After writing it to a file I want to read it again in the same format and access the items to plot the results

You can create your own format

hash your params as follows

```
hash_key = '_'.join(['{0}_{1}'.format(k, v) for (k,v) in params.iteritems() ])
```

will produce something like this

```
'epsilon_0_C_1_gamma_0.0001'
```

I would loop over your structure returned as follows

```
 import csv
 with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
     csvObj = csv.writer(output)
     # write headers
     csvObj = csv.writerow(['params','mean','std'])
     for cv_output in cv_outputs:
         std = cv_output['std']
         mean = cv_output['mean']
         params = cv_output['params']
         hash_params = '_'.join(['{0}_{1}'.format(k, v) for (k,v) in params.iteritems() ])
         csvObj.writerow([hash_params, mean, std])
```

Or alternatively you could split the `params` keys to columns. I will leave that for you to decide.

Comment: Not a lot more can be said really.

Comment: it is a list of tuples because when you write
print(type(scores[1])) you will get <class 'sklearn.grid_search._CVScoreTuple'>

Comment: @AhmadSultan But a `'sklearn.grid_search._CVScoreTuple'` is *not* a Python tuple. What you have given in your question is apparently the string representation of a list of custom objects.

Comment: @AhmadSultan what do you want to achieve from this `hierarchy `  - the ability to loop over the results? to interpret the result? reformat the object? - As a data scientist myself I only pay attention to the variance between `cv` and the `params` the form is unimportant as along as I feel the "best" model has been found.

Comment: After writing it to a file I want to read it again in the same format and access the items to plot the results.